# OpenCV's projectPoints function

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm currently trying to implement a example of OpenCV's [projectPoints](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#projectpoints) method. The idea behind this method is taking as input a set of 3D points, translation/rotation vector's of a given camera and its distortion coeficients, output the corresponding 2D points in the image plane.
The source of code is as follows:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::vector<cv::Point3d> Generate3DPoints();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Read 3D points
    std::vector<cv::Point3d> objectPoints = Generate3DPoints();
    std::vector<cv::Point2d> imagePoints;

    cv::Mat intrisicMat(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type); // Intrisic matrix
    intrisicMat.at<double>(0, 0) = 1.6415318549788924e+003;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(1, 0) = 0;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(2, 0) = 0;

    intrisicMat.at<double>(0, 1) = 0;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(1, 1) = 1.7067753507885654e+003;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(2, 1) = 0;

    intrisicMat.at<double>(0, 2) = 5.3262822453148601e+002;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(1, 2) = 3.8095355839052968e+002;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(2, 2) = 1;

    cv::Mat rVec(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type); // Rotation vector
    rVec.at<double>(0) = -3.9277902400761393e-002;
    rVec.at<double>(1) = 3.7803824407602084e-002;
    rVec.at<double>(2) = 2.6445674487856268e-002;

    cv::Mat tVec(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type); // Translation vector
    tVec.at<double>(0) = 2.1158489381208221e+000;
    tVec.at<double>(1) = -7.6847683212704716e+000;
    tVec.at<double>(2) = 2.6169795190294256e+001;

    cv::Mat distCoeffs(5, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);   // Distortion vector
    distCoeffs.at<double>(0) = -7.9134632415085826e-001;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(1) = 1.5623584435644169e+000;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(2) = -3.3916502741726508e-002;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(3) = -1.3921577146136694e-002;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(4) = 1.1430734623697941e+002;

    std::cout << "Intrisic matrix: " << intrisicMat << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Rotation vector: " << rVec << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Translation vector: " << tVec << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Distortion coef: " << distCoeffs << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> projectedPoints;

    cv::projectPoints(objectPoints, rVec, tVec, intrisicMat, distCoeffs, projectedPoints);

    /*for (unsigned int i = 0; i < projectedPoints.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Image point: " << imagePoints[i] << " Projected to " << projectedPoints[i] << std::endl;
    }*/

    std::cout << "Press any key to exit.";
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}

std::vector<cv::Point3d> Generate3DPoints()
{
    std::vector<cv::Point3d> points;

    double x, y, z;

    x = .5; y = .5; z = -.5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = .5; y = .5; z = .5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = -.5; y = .5; z = .5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = -.5; y = .5; z = -.5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = .5; y = -.5; z = -.5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = -.5; y = -.5; z = -.5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = -.5; y = -.5; z = .5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
    { 
        std::cout << points[i] << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    return points;
}
```

The application crashes when I try to run the projectPoints method and I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What/where exactly is the error?

Comment: The application crashes at:  cv::projectPoints(objectPoints, rVec, tVec, intrisicMat, distCoeffs, projectedPoints). The error is "First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCC3940D in OpenCVTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000000002BB840."

Comment: I have an Assertion failed : `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in create, file /home/me/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1486
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/me/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1486: error: (-215) mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0) in function create`

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong output. The error was: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN
(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in cv::_OutputArray::create, f
ile C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp
, line 1486

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems to be complaining about the type of the output vector of points. Try to replace your call to `projectPoints`:

```
cv::projectPoints(objectPoints, rVec, tVec, intrisicMat, distCoeffs, projectedPoints);
```

by this call:

```
cv::projectPoints(objectPoints, rVec, tVec, intrisicMat, distCoeffs, imagePoints);
```

This uses the variable of type `std::vector<cv::Point2d>` instead of `std::vector<cv::Point2f>`.