# Conversion of cloud data into 2d image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-studio-2013, point-cloud-library

I am using OpenCV2(3.0.0) with IDE VS2013. My requirement is we are having a 3D point cloud data (with parameters XYZ), can i convert that 3d point point cloud into a 2d image and can we convert the cloud data to image using Opencv without linking PCL.

Is it Possible???

If possible can anyone suggest me how to convert, with a sample code of OpenCV.

Any suggestions will be helpful
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The question is not really clear. What do you mean by "convert" a point cloud to a 2d image?
I will assume that by "convert" you mean project.
In opencv a point cloud, or any 3d point for that matter can be **projected** onto a 2d image using `projectpoints`: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#projectpoints.

This is based on the pinhole camera model, take a look here for example:
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/FUSIELLO4/tutorial.html

You can alsot take a look at this question:
[OpenCV's projectPoints function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244603/opencvs-projectpoints-function)

Bare in mind that you will not be able to reconstruct you original 3d data (since the depth info was lost in the projection process)

To simplify things, we can use a "perfect" projection model (no camera lens distortions) with an arbitrary focal length (if you wish to display the image, you need to play around with the focal length according to your data, such that the projected points' values are in not too high, for example not above 2048, which is the width of a 2k resolution image).

Here's an example:

```
#include <string>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


std::vector<cv::Point3d> Generate3DPoints();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Read 3D points
    std::vector<cv::Point3d> objectPoints = Generate3DPoints();
    std::vector<cv::Point2d> imagePoints;

    int f = 5;  //focal length

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < objectPoints.size(); i++)
    {
        cv::Point3d orig_point = objectPoints[i];
        imagePoints.push_back(cv::Point2d(
            f*orig_point.x / orig_point.z,  //x' = f*x/z
            f*orig_point.y / orig_point.z)  //y' = f*y/z
            );
    }
}

std::vector<cv::Point3d> Generate3DPoints()
{
    std::vector<cv::Point3d> points;

    double x, y, z;

    x = .5; y = .5; z = -.5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = .5; y = .5; z = .5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = -.5; y = .5; z = .5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = -.5; y = .5; z = -.5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = .5; y = -.5; z = -.5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = -.5; y = -.5; z = -.5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    x = -.5; y = -.5; z = .5;
    points.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << points[i] << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    return points;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daniel, I am working on it and if i face any problem i will get back to you.