# Using OpenCV projectPoints to overlay real world data on a photo

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a photograph and matching camera position (x,y,z), orientation (yaw, pitch and roll), camera matrix (Cx,Cy, Fx,Fy), and radial and tangential correction parameters.  I would like to overlay some additional 3d information on the photo which is provided in the same coordinate system.  Looking at a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244603/opencvs-projectpoints-function) I feel I should be able to do this OpenCV projectPoints function as follows;

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int ProjectMyPoints()
{
    std::vector<cv::Point3d> objectPoints;
    std::vector<cv::Point2d> imagePoints;

    // Camera position
    double CameraX = 709095.949, CameraY = 730584.110, CameraZ = 64.740;

    // Camera orientation (converting from Grads to radians)
    double PI = 3.14159265359;
    double Pitch = -99.14890023 * (PI / 200.0),
        Yaw = PI + 65.47067336 * (PI / 200.0),
        Roll = 194.92713428 * (PI / 200.0);

    // Input data in real world coordinates 
    double x, y, z;
    x = 709092.288; y = 730582.891; z = 62.837; objectPoints.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));
    x = 709091.618; y = 730582.541; z = 62.831; objectPoints.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));
    x = 709092.131; y = 730581.602; z = 62.831; objectPoints.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));
    x = 709092.788; y = 730581.973; z = 62.843; objectPoints.push_back(cv::Point3d(x, y, z));

    // Coefficients for camera matrix
    double CV_CX = 1005.1951672908998,
        CV_CY = 1010.36740512214021,
        CV_FX = 1495.61455114326009,
        CV_FY = 1495.61455114326009,

        // Distortion co-efficients

        CV_K1 = -1.74729071186991E-1,
        CV_K2 = 1.18342592220238E-1,
        CV_K3 = -2.29972026710921E-2,
        CV_K4 = 0.00000000000000E+0,
        CV_K5 = 0.00000000000000E+0,
        CV_K6 = 0.00000000000000E+0,
        CV_P1 = -3.46272954067614E-4,
        CV_P2 = -4.45389772269491E-4;

    // Intrisic matrix / camera matrix

    cv::Mat intrisicMat(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type); 
    intrisicMat.at<double>(0, 0) = CV_FX;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(1, 0) = 0;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(2, 0) = 0;

    intrisicMat.at<double>(0, 1) = 0;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(1, 1) = CV_FY;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(2, 1) = 0;

    intrisicMat.at<double>(0, 2) = CV_CX;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(1, 2) = CV_CY;
    intrisicMat.at<double>(2, 2) = 1;

    // Rotation matrix created from orientation
    rRot.at<double>(0, 0) = cos(Yaw)*cos(Pitch);
    rRot.at<double>(1, 0) = sin(Yaw)*cos(Pitch);
    rRot.at<double>(2, 0) = -sin(Pitch);

    rRot.at<double>(0, 1) = cos(Yaw)*sin(Pitch)*sin(Roll) - sin(Yaw)*cos(Roll);
    rRot.at<double>(1, 1) = sin(Yaw)*sin(Pitch)*sin(Roll) + cos(Yaw)*cos(Roll);
    rRot.at<double>(2, 1) = cos(Pitch)*sin(Roll);

    rRot.at<double>(0, 2) = cos(Yaw)*sin(Pitch)*cos(Roll) + sin(Yaw)*sin(Roll);
    rRot.at<double>(1, 2) = sin(Yaw)*sin(Pitch)*cos(Roll) - cos(Yaw)*sin(Roll);;
    rRot.at<double>(2, 2) = cos(Pitch)*cos(Roll);

    // Convert 3x3 rotation matrix to 1x3 rotation vector    
    cv::Mat rVec(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type); // Rotation vector
    cv::Rodrigues(rRot, rVec);

    cv::Mat tVec(3, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type); // Translation vector
    tVec.at<double>(0) = CameraX;
    tVec.at<double>(1) = CameraY;
    tVec.at<double>(2) = CameraZ;

    cv::Mat distCoeffs(5, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);   // Distortion vector
    distCoeffs.at<double>(0) = CV_K1;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(1) = CV_K2;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(2) = CV_P1;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(3) = CV_P2;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(4) = CV_K3;

    std::cout << "Intrisic matrix: " << intrisicMat << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Rotation vector: " << rVec << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Translation vector: " << tVec << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Distortion coef: " << distCoeffs << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> projectedPoints;

    cv::projectPoints(objectPoints, rVec, tVec, intrisicMat, distCoeffs, imagePoints);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < imagePoints.size(); ++i)
         std::cout << "Image point: " << imagePoints[i] << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press any key to exit.";
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

The rotation matrix is taken from [this post](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node102.html) as follows

[image]

and is converted to a Rodriques vector as described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#rodrigues). I had assumed the translation was for removal camera position and hence put the camera in the translation vector.  Problem is, it doesn't work.  If I zero out the translation I get coordinates close to pixel coordinates but not exactly similar (i.e. using a conformal transformation to compare the shapes shows high residuals).  Any idea how to go about fixing this.  FWIW, the target coordinates should be

1   1448    1680,
2   1393    1578,
3   1052    1605,
4   1053    1702

as shown below;

[image]

My feeling is I'm missing something obvious but any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you divide your angles by 200?

Comment: They're supplied to me in gradians in this case, as is the norm for surveying in continental Europe. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian

Comment: There are many Euler angles representation (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix)). You could use [`solvePnP`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga549c2075fac14829ff4a58bc931c033d) to compute the camera pose from the 3D object coordinates and the 2D image coordinates to compare with your data?

Comment: @Catree, was thinking along similar lines myself.  Will give it a go and see how it pans out.  Thanks for the link to solvePnP

Comment: @Catree, tried this but even if I reduce the input data based on the camera position it still comes up with a translation vector.  Also tried solvePnPRANSAC with the same results. Looking at the points I've selected, they're quite close and co-planar which might be giving the solver too much wriggle room.  I'll try again with more points with greater separation.

Comment: If you can use the 4 points as in the picture, `solvePnP` should be ok. You can estimate the camera pose of a planar object with `solvePnP` (e.g. augmented reality with marker, ...), a degenerate case is for instance some co-linear points.

Comment: Unless the object frame and the camera frame are at the same position (only the orientation differs), you should have a translation and a rotation vectors. The output of `solvePnP` allows you to compute the 3D coordinate of a point expressed in the object frame in the camera frame: `P_cam = [R | t] . P_obj`. The intrinsic parameters allow to project into the image plane.