# How can i find the position of "boundary boxed" object with lidar and camera?

Tags: opencv, ros, robotics, gazebo-simu, pcl

This question is related to my final project. In gazebo simulation environment, I am trying to detect obstacles' colors and calculate the distance between robot and obstacles. I am currently identifying their colors with the help of OpenCV methods ([object with boundary box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Pyz.png)) but I don't know how can i calculate their distances between robot. I have my robot's position. I will not use stereo. I know the size of the obstacles. Waiting for your suggestions and ideas. Thank you!

My robot's topics :

- cameras/camera/camera_info *(Type: sensor_msgs/CameraInfo)*
- cameras/camera/image_raw *(Type: sensor_msgs/Image)*
- sensors/lidars/points *(Type: sensor_msgs/PointCloud2)*

Comment: There isn't enough information to give you an answer here really. Do you have the positions of all the obstacles in a global fixed reference co-ordinate system? Are you using stereo vision? Is the camera space calibrated? If so how? Do you know the sizes of the obstacles a priori? So many questions...

Comment: Sorry for insufficient information. I don't have the positions of the all obstacles. I am trying to find that. I just have my robot's position. I am not using stereo vision. I just want to fuse lidar and my camera.  Camera space is not calibrated Actually, i dont know what that it means. I know the size of the obstacles. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can project the point cloud into image space, e.g., with OpenCV (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244603/opencvs-projectpoints-function)). That way, you can filter all points that are within the bounding box in the image space. Of course, projection errors because of differences between both sensors need to be addressed, e.g., by removing the lower and upper quartile of points regarding the distance to the LiDAR sensor. You can use the remaining points to estimate the distance, eventually.

We have such a system running and it works just fine.